# Docker-Compose for multiple github microservices

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

I'm trying to find a solution for managing my local environment using `docker-compose` for multiple microservices.

Each microservice has own github repository and can depend on another microservice for example `Order` service communicate with `Product` service.

All microservices create one complete sollution so when working locally I need to run every microservice with `docker-compose up` - maybe there is a way to automate this with create just one `docker-compose` that contains all microservices containers.

At this moment I got this directory structure.

```
Projects
  Project A
    - docker-compose.yml (contains 3 containers)
  Project B
    - docker-compose.yml (contains 3 containers)
```

Comment: you can copy all services and create a new docker-compose.yml file or you can start all docker-composes in one command like `docker-compose  -f ProjectA/docker-compose.yml -f ProjectB/docker-compose.yml ... up`. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `docker-compose.yaml` that contain all those services. Then you can set Dockerfile path for each service.

```
Projects
  Project A
  Project B
  docker-compose.yml
```

`docker-compose.yaml` example:

```
version: '3'

services:
   project-a:
     build:
       context: ./Project-A
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
   project-b:
     build:
       context: ./Project-B
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Comment: Hello, with that approach I see one problem but maybe there is a solution for this. - I don't know.  `docker-compose.yml` for `Project A` contains let say 3 containers and `Project B` also 3 containers, so single `docker-compose.yml` can grow really big.

Comment: You can have multiple YAML files. See [Extending Services](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services).